# Hide multiple detail bands

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a report with a subreport to add a logo to the main report. In this subreport I have 2 detail bands to support two differently sized logos; one is long and the other is about a 3rd a long (width). kind of like this...

```
...........................
|---------logo------------|
address 1, address 2
...........................
|__logo__|    address 1
|        |    address 2
...........................
```

Between the 1st and 2nd row of periods is the **Details 1** band and between the 2nd and 3rd is **Details 2** band.

I am trying to use the "Print When Expression" to toggle the 1st or 2nd Detail band depending on the value of `$F{LogoName}`.

**Detail 1** band:

```
new Boolean($F{LogoName}=="acompanyname")
```

**Detail 2** band:

```
new Boolean($F{LogoName}!="acompanyname")
```

but it does not work.

Have also tried these:

```
(($F{LogoName}=="acompanyname")?Boolean.TRUE:Boolean.FALSE)
(($F{LogoName}!="acompanyname")?Boolean.TRUE:Boolean.FALSE)
```

The `$F{LogoName}` is "acompanyname".

Every time I run the report only **Detail 2** band shows. I can not get details 1 to show at all and I am not getting any error messages.

Any help is welcome.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$F{LogoName}.equals( "acompanyname" )
```

In Java, the equality operator (`==`), when used on objects, checks to see if they are the same reference to the same object. This one catches all report developers without a lot of Java programming experience. You could write:

```
$F{LogoName} == $F{LogoName}
```

That would return `true`, as you expect, because both objects on either side of the equals operator are the same. Consider the following:

```
public class T { 
  public static void main( String args[] ) {                                    
    String s1 = "hello";                                                        
    String s2 = (new StringBuilder( s1 )).toString();                           

    System.out.println( s1 );
    System.out.println( s2 );
    System.out.println( s1 == s2 );
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
hello
hello
false
```

The *values* of the strings objects are the same, but the *references* to the strings are different. The equals operation compares the references, not the values.

Comment: Dave, thanks for the response and sorry for the late accepted. I ended up removing the code and just did one band for the logo. I do see what you mean about the reference being compared and I willhave to keep that in mind in the furure.